# Animate SVG clipping mask

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg, clip-path

I have an SVG which consists of curvy lines. I want to create a clipping mask of this, for a blurred white rectangle, and translate that to make it look like the lines are glowing as the rectangle moves. Im close, but I cannot get the SVG to clip to the lines, and for some odd reason the animation does not repeat infinitely.

JS:

```
  <svg className="absolute inset-0 h-screen w-screen" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none">
    <linearGradient id="shimmer-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="8%" y2="0%">
      <stop offset="0%" style={{ stopColor: ' rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', stopOpacity: 0 }} />
      <stop offset="50%" style={{ stopColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)', stopOpacity: 0.5 }} />
      <stop offset="70%" style={{ stopColor: ' rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)', stopOpacity: 0 }} />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="shimmer-mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#shimmer-gradient)" />
    </mask>
    <g stroke="#fff" opacity=".15" id="dash" fill="none">
      <path d="m900 812.905-1.11-605.685-2.1-43.075-3.72-28.401-4.89-16.097-7.77-9.906-5.7-1.856-5.31.298-13.59 5.203-59.97 41.518-26.07 16.558-33.48 18.089-37.2 16.517-39.18 14.309-44.82 13.604-51.72 13.171-51.9 11.287-76.62 14.133-75 11.504-74.7 9.132-63.72 5.244-41.25 1.464-41.34-.651-30.3-1.924-72.33-6.599-35.76-1.91M859.14 812.905l-11.73-19.62-14.79-16.572-14.43-9.268-7.2-2.426-8.52-1.192-12.21 1.138-11.73 3.726-35.43 18.388-13.08 5.569-12.42 3.238-10.56.962-10.68-.528-11.76-2.005-58.62-17.399-14.79-2.954-15.84-1.449-21.33 1.138-49.29 9.905-13.89 1.653-12.57.433-23.07-1.558-62.7-10.094-33.48-2.968-30.45.921-55.53 6.884-30.33 1.707-39.36-1.653-89.46-9.255-39.21-2.452-41.34.19-53.22 4.078M908.28 812.743l4.59-9.526 3.39-2.846 3.09-.758 4.92.853 4.83 2.399 11.76 10.04" />
      <path d="m903.78 812.499 6.63-30.718 4.77-6.978 3.3-1.897 3.39-.421 7.47 2.128 9.87 6.761 29.55 31.423M879 812.932l-16.38-44.918-9.9-18.984-11.49-17.113-12.15-13.564-13.32-10.582-13.14-6.667-14.1-3.469-12.48-.244-13.38 2.331-14.37 4.864-45.57 19.607-14.19 3.483-15.84 1.341-14.22-.894-15.15-2.588-68.94-17.534-16.95-2.71-15.96-1.26-14.37.081-14.16 1.165-57.18 9.784-30.09 2.208-32.16-1.599-93.21-12.371-26.43-2.493-25.02-1.26-44.88.921-73.89 7.222-35.61 2.236-43.17.014-50.04-2.683" />
      <path d="m902.1 812.336 2.49-29.241 4.44-21.043 5.94-11.03 3.75-2.764 4.83-.881 8.97 2.521 12.81 8.807 38.94 39.322 17.01 14.323" />
      <path d="m901.26 812.187 2.31-40.636 4.35-26.748 6.66-15.122 5.07-4.268 4.68-1.125 5.16.556 5.64 2.005 12.66 7.886 43.8 40.989 18.27 13.997 18.6 8.753 9.54 2.236 8.79.854 15.96-.935 19.41-4.214 69.24-23.333 27.42-7.778 24.6-5 26.22-2.764 19.77-.122 17.73 1.355 70.53 12.208 17.49 1.87 17.94.651 33.84-1.911 74.13-10.054 35.37-2.9 30.51.488 52.59 5.502 28.59 1.368 26.88-1.016 54.6-5.19 28.5-1.829 26.97.108 33.72 2.507" />
      <path d="m900.81 812.228 2.34-55.271 4.32-30.013 7.65-18.333 4.83-4.336 5.88-1.762 5.25.366 5.97 1.789 13.62 7.547 48.21 41.802 19.35 13.699 19.35 8.414 9.66 2.155 10.56.962 17.73-1.098 21.24-4.39 70.95-22.249 33.99-9.146 26.4-5.176 27.93-3.117 23.34-.461 19.59 1.206 20.76 2.683 55.68 9.336 17.58 1.667 17.94.542 33.93-1.789 74.49-9.444 33.6-2.805 34.14.231 56.28 5.474 30.42 1.206 28.65-1.206 68.91-6.03 26.88-.976M891.51 812.621l-7.35-38.875-9.81-33.862-12.06-29.579-14.88-26.802-17.55-23.049-19.68-18.265-20.13-12.453-10.56-4.417-12.15-3.455-19.08-2.141-21.06 1.829-20.34 5.19-53.01 18.157-18.12 3.563-19.53 1.233-14.31-.636-17.37-2.128-91.86-18.685-25.68-3.726-22.98-1.952-21.57-.447-21.48.908-24.57 2.507-67.29 9.024-28.44 1.965-26.97.366-30.51-.962-42.72-2.887L.63 616.281" />
      <path d="m900.51 812.485 1.98-64.213 4.32-36.531 7.98-21.612 5.97-5.895 7.23-2.235 5.31.298 6.18 1.639 16.56 8.51 49.98 40.446 20.22 13.442 19.71 8.265 11.28 2.507 10.53 1.016 19.59-.894 23.28-4.322 84.99-24.445 36.45-8.834 28.5-5.027 29.82-3.008 23.34-.461 21.45 1.152 22.59 2.696 54.45 8.483 19.38 1.761 17.97.528 33.96-1.598 80.1-9.418 33.75-2.466 34.11.407 58.17 5.366 26.88 1.016 30.48-1.057 51.3-4.377" />
      <path d="m900.36 812.282 1.59-71.544 4.83-46.273 3.75-13.713 4.71-9.526 6.69-6.626 6.99-2.452 7.08.122 7.92 1.897 14.97 6.992 15.06 10.108 40.05 30.867 22.32 13.753 21.87 8.374 11.52 2.29 10.56.962 21.42-.813 25.26-4.255 93.24-24.593 43.47-9.783 33.87-5.488 29.94-2.791 25.14-.542 21.48.989 22.77 2.412 56.61 8.116 33.78 2.155 37.62-1.396 83.94-9.187 37.41-2.371 35.88.8 69.03 5.663 23.37.204 25.08-1.084M897.6 812.512l-4.56-53.617-8.85-47.805-12.57-39.417-17.73-36.517-21.06-30.23-26.37-26.72-15.51-11.911-15.72-9.905-16.71-8.523-17.52-6.992-19.62-5.718-19.98-3.672-17.67-1.504-21.54.298-15.78 1.599-18.48 3.198-58.41 14.431-26.49 5.081-28.14 2.656-32.34-.217-54.51-5.271-140.97-19.729-97.26-11.965-99.96-10.447-88.53-7.276" />
      <path d="m900.24 812.377 1.62-85.365 4.47-46.287 3.57-14.539 4.95-11.165 6.57-7.548 8.91-3.875 7.08-.244 8.4 1.409 18.45 7.67 19.86 12.56 40.5 28.821 23.7 13.279 22.74 7.9 11.64 2.154 12.36 1.044 21.48-.678 22.32-3.116 26.13-5.475 80.49-19.918 37.29-8.13 42.09-7.154 40.38-4.025 28.74-.65 23.25 1.043 78.06 9.675 33.87 2.019 41.19-1.545 82.44-8.55 39.21-2.358 34.14.597 72.66 5.677" />
      <path d="m900.18 812.959 1.5-97.56 4.44-49.552 3.84-16.165 5.67-12.737 7.5-8.252 8.94-3.889 6.99-.596 10.41 1.165L969 632.46l20.28 11.409 46.2 30.04 27.39 13.984 23.58 7.398 15.24 2.439 12.48.786 23.25-.813 27.6-3.699 152.94-32.601 42.33-6.87 38.52-4.133 30.42-1.301 26.94.624 28.26 2.452 57.33 7.033 35.73 1.747 41.16-1.693 77.37-7.642 31.98-2.277 34.17-.515 37.47 2.087" />
      <path d="m900.15 800.182 1.47-98.373 4.62-51.978 4.35-17.778 5.94-12.71 8.49-8.943 10.59-4.254 8.82-.691 10.44 1.124 21.72 7.155 22.65 11.558 50.37 29.674 30.21 13.903 13.17 4.254 14.46 3.293 13.74 1.91 14.28.841 25.08-.773 31.29-3.74 163.83-31.612 47.76-7.235 38.64-3.903 30.42-1.301 28.77.57 24.81 1.937 64.62 7.222 35.85 1.301 35.82-1.463 91.71-8.388 44.73-2.181" />
      <path d="m900 758.258 1.8-252.843 3.75-47.113 7.44-35.61 7.32-19.227 9.99-18.144 14.22-19.281 17.07-18.794 21.75-20.542 25.29-20.623 23.1-15.501 18.96-9.77 19.77-7.019 18.03-3.631 19.53-1.328 23.19 1.22 42.12 7.046 128.76 29.091 45.15 8.103 44.52 6.504 76.92 8.483 162.81 13.658 167.43 15.704M900 799.382l-.75-275.607-1.8-52.831-3.33-36.558-6.96-33.997-10.86-25.528-14.73-18.306-9.75-7.778-11.07-6.409-16.26-6.396-18.96-4.634-24.06-3.333-30.24-2.006-98.94-1.043-205.17 1.098-93.36 3.062-80.28 4.824-79.68 6.558L.06 358.912" />
      <path d="m899.85 557.65-2.43-123.562-3.33-35.745-5.67-28.333-9.24-23.184-11.49-15.393-17.25-12.317-9.18-3.889-12.24-3.414-25.92-3.198-35.97-.041-155.37 8.713-183.06 6.355-73.38 3.496-124.38 9.065L.24 358.194M900.15 569.805l1.08-87.804 2.88-51.206 5.67-37.303 10.77-33.78 9-18.252 12.3-19.553 14.49-19.241L975 281.528l15.96-15.474 16.68-13.482 15.69-9.905 16.65-7.412 13.83-3.78 13.77-1.83 14.34-.149 17.55 1.735 29.46 6.07 76.62 21.301 44.64 10.542 43.98 7.154 38.94 3.13 32.37.136 30.3-1.843 112.47-14.485 31.8-2.764 30.42-1.477 36-.529 46.77.651 145.2 5.867" />
      <path d="m900 629.696-1.11-191.055-2.04-44.702-3.51-31.666-5.97-25.867-9.6-20.677-13.47-14.133-8.82-5.149-9.6-3.645-9.69-2.155-12.24-1.273-28.68.623-112.98 13.672-56.19 5.664-67.53 4.932L387 323.466l-88.98 6.07-86.64 7.507L.21 357.517" />
/* There are more Paths here, didn't paste all... */
    </g>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <rect id="test" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" mask="url(#shimmer-mask)" />
    </clipPath>
    <use clip-path="url(#myClip)" href="#test" />
  </svg>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes translx {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-10%);
  }

  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

#myClip rect {
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation: translx 8s, infinite linear
}
```